# How can i put the <p> tag infront of the <progressbar> tag

Tags: html, css, ui-design

I wanted to do some UI-Design and came across a little problem. Basically the  tag should be the background of that

tag -which is only red so that it can be found more easily-.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kuv4.png)

HTML-Code:

```
<div class="tournament">
        <p>
            &lt;GET system.template.tournament.date&gt; <progress id="value" max="8"></progress>
        </p>
        <button>Information</button>
    </div>
    <p class="playerNumber">
        <span id="players">4</span>/<span id="max">8</span> <span id="plural">Players</span> in
    </p>
```

CSS-Code:

```
.tournament {
  background-color: #202020;
  width: 98%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  height: 121px;
}

.tournament p {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.tournament button {
  margin-left: 90%;
  margin-top: 43px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 35px;
  border-color: #666666;
}

.tournament progress {
  border-color: #666666;
  background-color: #202020;
  width: 285%;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 80%;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar { background: #151515; }
progress::-webkit-progress-value { background: #151515; }
progress { color: #151515; }

.playerNumber {
  text-align: left;
  color: red;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

Basically that p-element shows some information related to that progressbar. In this case it says "4/8 Players in" which is refered to the tournament. Thats why the progressbar is 50%-full.

Its not a problem if you have a solution that comes without a

-tag but allowes me to write something on the progressbar.

*Why am i asking here?*

1. z-index didnt solve my problem as you can see in the code
2. I didnt found an answer to my problem on this forum
3. Google had no clue either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put the `.playerNumber` element inside the `.tournament` element.

just adjust the positions using, `top`, `left` css props for `.playerNumber` element...

then you would need this css and...

```css
.playerNumber {
  text-align: left;
  color: red;
  left: 300px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
  display:block;
}


.tournament progress {
  border-color: #666666;
  background-color: #202020;
  width: 285%;
  height: 45px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

...and html like this

```html
<div class="tournament">
  <p>
    &lt;GET system.template.tournament.date&gt; <progress id="value" max="8"></progress>
  </p>
  <button>Information</button>
  
<p class="playerNumber">
  <span id="players">4</span>/<span id="max">8</span> <span id="plural">Players</span> in
</p>
</div>
```

[test here](https://jsfiddle.net/nyr28v0w/)

Comment: First of all thank you for letting me know how i can move the p tag in this case... I still dont understand, why margin-[position] doesnt work since it workes normally...

But i have a problem with the solution you came up with... Its not responsive...

Full-HD-Screen: https://www.clanneko.tk/Files/Asuna_1163ddcc-ef9e-4e5b-bc26-15c872c5e9cc_5dk_07-08-2022_12-11.png

4K-Screen: https://www.clanneko.tk/Files/Asuna_d6991d6c-ffe2-4612-a352-d12ad7e5e7f9_5dl_07-08-2022_12-11.png

Comment: @SakuraQueen you need to use `top` and `left` instead, as now is inside and next to the same elements

Comment: Did that.

CSS right now: https://pastebin.com/zg0SPTRr

Comment: Figured it out. I just had to use "left: randomNumber px" for the progressbar element to